# JSON to DataFrame in Spark, return value is null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a key value pair where value is JSON.

xyz= (null, "{"ID": "1", "Invoice No": "XYZ-123", "Invoice Date": "22/8/2022",  "Customer ID": "AC3321", "Product Name": "Mobile", "Price": "10000.00", "Quantity": "1"}")

I want to store this value into a table using Spark, where column name will be ID, Invoice No, Invoice Date, Customer ID, Product Name, Price, Quantity.

I tried in blow way.

```
abc= df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

schema =  StructType()\
    .add("ID",StringType())\
    .add("Invoice No",StringType())\
    .add("Invoice Date",StringType())\
    .add("Customer ID",StringType())\
    .add("Product Name",StringType())\
    .add("Price",StringType())\
    .add("Quantity",StringType())


personStringDF1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value as string)").select(from_json(col("value"),schema).alias("json_value")).selectExpr("json_value.*")
display(personStringDF1)
```

But all value comes null.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your behaviour.
Unfortunately, this works as expected :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col

columns =  ["key", "value"]
data= [("1", '{"ID": "1", "Invoice No": "XYZ-123", "Invoice Date": "22/8/2022", "Customer ID": "AC3321", "Product Name": "Mobile", "Price": "10000.00", "Quantity": "1"}')]

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data,
    columns
)

abc= df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

schema =  StructType()\
    .add("ID",StringType())\
    .add("Invoice No",StringType())\
    .add("Invoice Date",StringType())\
    .add("Customer ID",StringType())\
    .add("Product Name",StringType())\
    .add("Price",StringType())\
    .add("Quantity",StringType())


personStringDF1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value as string)").select(from_json(col("value"),schema).alias("json_value")).selectExpr("json_value.*")
display(personStringDF1)
```

[image: personStringDF1_results]

Could you provide more examples or more code ?